# QGIS - Draw line along points, using next closest point as next vertex

Tags: qgis, points-to-line

I have a bunch of points which I have extracted from line features. Now I want to connect them back to a line, but unfortunately, they are not sorted in the correct way, so I always end up with a wild mess.

So I thought about an approach where the line creation starts at a defined start point and then connects the points one by one, always chosing the next vertex based on the minimum distance from the previous one.
But I have no idea how to do that in QGIS. Aside from the distance to the next point, I have nothing else to determine the line direction.

Any suggestions welcome (incl. Python coding).

[image]

Comment: See here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382057/create-road-network-from-points/382246#382246

Comment: or here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/386082/connecting-points-to-lines-in-order-using-qgis?rq=1

Comment: Or here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/419209/88814

Comment: Are you sure you do not have any attribute (including id) you could use for ordering? Do you still have original lines available which intersect all these points?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ProcessX-Plug-In](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ProcessX/). It has an algorithm "**Nearest Points To Path**", you will find in your `processing toolbox --> processx --> vector - creation`:

[image]

In your case you may want to use `$x` as `OrderBy Expression`, to make sure the line starts at most-western point.

Example result:

[image]

*Disclaimer: I am the developer of this Plug-In*

Comment: Using the x-Coordinate is not option. The points resemble a natural river and the "closest" point is not always the next one in x-direction. As shown in the screenshot in the question, the river can move mostly west, but make a short curves towards east as well before continuing west.

Comment: In this case, add a new field to your layer, give the startpoint of the river the value 1 and all other points the value 2. Then use this new field as OrderBy-Expression. But maybe we also misunderstood each other? Just give it a try and report back.

Answer (score 1):

If the first answer does not work, you can try the MST plug-in. In the plug-in you can select a point layer. It will connect the points along the shortest path